# Search multiple keywords in SQL Server and sort result as per maximum matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few keywords which i would like to search in a column of table tblSearch.

For example keywords are sql, java, net. 
And the columns values are like below

1. acce java net take
2. share java net access sql python
3. no tech
4. sql server with

So here I want to get the result in order 2, 1, 4.

Trying to use like statement but how should I order them based on maximum number of keywords matched. I do not have option of Full text search. Is there any simplest way of doing this without using many like statements.

Comment: Are keywords are single variable which store comma separated list? or each keyword is separate variable

Comment: right now single variable and splitted in a table but if required then i can keep them separate as well, thats not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Full-text search has an automatic ranking function based on the matching.

If you have built your full-text index appropriately, with the unique clustered index on the ID column (which I'm assuming in your case is marked by the values 1,2,3 and 4 in your example), then all you have to do is run the below query.

```
DECLARE @search varchar(100) = '"sql*" AND "java*" AND "net*"'

SELECT t.*
FROM tlbSearch t
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (tblSearch, searchColumn, @search) Ktbl ON T.ID = Ktbl.[key]
ORDER BY Ktbl.[rank] ASC
```

In order to take advantage of full-text search you have to use full-text appropriate filtering functionalities. The equivalents of `LIKE` and `=` in full-text are `FREETEXT` and `CONTAINS`, along with their `FREETEXTTABLE` and [**`CONTAINSTABLE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) which return a table with your required `rank` column automatically.

Also, in order for this to work, all of your keywords need to be in the same column - turns out to be a bit of redundancy, but that's what you need for full-text search. So, your tblSearch needs to have this structure:

```
+----+----------------------------------+
| ID |           searchColumn           |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | acce java net take               |
|  2 | share java net access sql python |
|  3 | no tech                          |
|  4 | sql server with                  |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

*(if you want to post a table with data on Stackoverflow like I did, [you can use this](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/))*